# Collecting parent-child information in a form without repeating any questions

Tags: forms, information-architecture

I'm looking for a way to collect information about a person's child(ren) and their their other parent(s). I would like to do this **without asking any questions twice**. Also, **asking the names and information of the child(ren) should occur first**.

For example, each child should have a set of questions like this:

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Name of Parent
4. How often does the parent see this child?
5. Who does this child live with the majority of the time?

Each parent should have a set of questions similar to the following:

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. How often are you in contact with this person?
4. Which child(ren) are theirs?

I'm looking for a way to have the user list their children, then link each child to the parent, without entering in the child's name or parent's name twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These objects and relationships are somewhat complicated and I have no way of knowing what your back-end implementation of these are, but I'll take a stab at a UI that might work.

#### Overview

It seems like there are 3 things going on here:

1. Collecting children information
2. Collecting parent information
3. Creating the connection

## Option 1

#### Keep users in a constant workflow

In order to do this in a smooth manner, you could allow the user to begin with adding a child. When you get to the parent selection, you could provide a drop down menu with all known parents, with an option to add a new one. The "Add New Parent" function could pop up a modal to allow you to create a new parent, then associate it to the child upon saving.

## Option 2

#### Manage children, manage parents, manage families

If you'd rather treat children and parents as distinct objects (meaning parents are not a "property" of a child), then you could provide a place to add/edit/delete all children and a place to add/edit/delete all parents, then have a "Families" view to manage the family relationships. Below is a sample Families" view that might get you thinking:

[image: family view]

<sub>(As sort of a tangent, parents and children are arguablty both `Person` objects that have several properties in common. There are then `Roles` that each `Person` can have. Assigning a `Person` to a `Parent` role gives them the attributes of `contactFrequency` and `children...`)</sub>

Comment: If you illustrate option 1 I will select this as the answer. It just seems a bit incomplete without that.

Comment: @invot Sorry, if I have time later I will. Hope this helped you though.